# Why do we only worry about the $\mathfrak{sl}(2)_{\alpha}$ subalgebras, with $\alpha$ simple, of semisimple Lie algebras?

Tags: representation-theory, lie-algebras, semisimple-lie-algebras

I am following Fuchs book on Lie algebras. Some topics are presented in a not so clear way, but it seems that he claims the following:

*Claim:* Writing $\text{span}_{\mathbb C}\{H^\alpha,E^{\pm \alpha}\} =: \mathfrak{sl}(2)_\alpha$, we have
\begin{equation}
 \mathfrak g = \bigoplus_{\alpha\in\Phi^+} \mathfrak {sl}(2)_\alpha 
\end{equation}
However, in section 13.2, he says that in order to study the representations of a semisimple Lie algebra, we only have to worry about the $\mathfrak{sl}(2)_{\alpha}$ with $\alpha$ a simple root. But of course we cannot ignore the non-simple positive roots in the decompostion above. So what's going on?

EDIT: This may help, although I am not sure how: From section 7.1 we can say that the semisimple Lie algebra is "algebraically generated" by the Cartan subalgebra generators and the ladder operators corresponding to simple roots. This "algebraic generation" means that we can not only use linear combinations but also the Lie brackets.

Comment: Well, at some point later it will be clear that any finite dimensional representation $V$ of semisimple lie algebra is determined by the action of Cartan subalgebra. Action of the whole Cartan on $V$ can be diagonalized simultaneously (because Cartan is a commutative  subalgebra of semisimple elements, almost a definition of Cartan). Functionals on $\mathfrak{h}$ appearing from this action are called weights and any irreducible $V$ is determined by its so called highest weight.
The same story goes for Lie groups, restriction to any maximal geometric torus determines the whole representation.

Comment: @RybinDmitry: Why not turn that into an answer?

Comment: I don't like the title; why claim that "we" only worry about something?

Comment: A Lie algebra with a decomposition as you write would have dimension divisible by 3, which is not the case in general (e.g., $\mathfrak{sl}_{3n}$, $n\ge 1$ does not).

Answer (score 1):

I'd like to expand my comment a little bit.
The fact that restriction of finite dimensional irreducible repr. $V$ to Cartan subalgebra $\mathfrak{h}$ is much more intuitively clear from Lie Group perspective:

Let $G$ be compact connected Lie group, corresponding to semisimple Lie algebra $\mathfrak{g}$. Here instead of Cartan we have some maximal compact torus $T$, isomorphic to $\mathrm{U}(1)^{\ell}$, where $\ell = \dim \mathfrak{h}$.
Character corresponding to $V$ is a function on conjugacy classes (this was true in case of finite discrete $G$, and the analogy is much deeper). It turns out that all conjugacy classes intersect $T$ nontrivially, so restriction to $T$ really determines the character of $V$, which determines $V$ completely.

Moreover Weyl group $\mathcal{W}$ measures exactly how nontrivial the intersection is:

$\mathrm{Theorem:}$ If $g_1, g_2$ are elements in $T$ which are in the same conjugacy class in $G$, then there is $w\in \mathcal{W}$ such that $w.g_1 = g_2$.

The reason why all that magic with Cartans and simple roots seems unmotivated is that the subject is so well developed and understood that it takes a few chapters in books to fully classify semisimple Lie algebras with description of their representations.